# How to effectively make div scrollable on hover only, and have it stay in that position when not hovering?

Tags: css

I know I can make a div scrollable on hover by using a fixed height, and by using `overflow:none` normally, and `overflow-y: scroll` on hover.

However, my div is a list of 30 items, and height 50px. If I hover, and scroll down to the 25th item, then move cursor out, the div changes to show the first few items (i.e. top of the div), NOT where I was previously just before moving cursor out.

How can I keep div in same position when I've hovered out?

Comment: Please share your code to debug easily

Comment: You will need javascript for this. When you move the cursor out of the element it goes back to being a no scroll element and lines itself back to the top since there is no scrolling and hides the overflow as the non-hover styling tells it to.

Comment: @NagaSaiA my code is literally #listOfTags{ overflow:none; height: 50vh; }
#listOfTags:hover{overflow-y: scroll;}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working here:

https://jsfiddle.net/wsxgt8yf/

Your CSS just needed to be changed to:

```
#listOfTags{ overflow:hidden; height: 50px; } #listOfTags:hover{overflow-y: scroll;}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was literally one word.